# Counting carriage return, Java

Tags: java, java.util.scanner, bufferedreader, arrays

I am trying to count carriage return occurrences within string input. I tried both `Scanner` and `BufferedReader`. With `Scanner`, `nextLine()` does not pick up Carriage Returns. `next()` with `Scanner` looks for tokens, such as a space in input, and token splits up the input. I want the entire input to be read as single input. This probably means I cannot use Scanner.

With `BufferedReader`, `readLine()` reads up to a Carriage Return, but does not return a Carriage Return in input. If I use "reader.read();" then it tells me that the variable user_input HAS to be int. user_input is supposed to be a string input that MAY have an integer, but it also may not. The only thing is that program would continue until input contains "/done". I would appreciate it if somebody would simply point me in the right direction!

```
try {
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
String user_input = "";

System.out.println("Enter a string: ");

while (!user_input.contains("/done"))  {


user_input = reader.readLine();        //cannot be readLine because it only reads up to a carriage return; it does NOT return carriage return
                                       //*Sadly, if I use "reader.read();" then it tells me that user_input HAS to be int. user_input is a string input
String input = user_input;
char[] c = input.toCharArray();
int[] f = new int[114];

System.out.println("Rest of program, I convert input to ascii decimal and report the occurences of each char that was used");

}

catch  (IOException e) {
e.printStackTrace();
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you're looking for?

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
scanner.useDelimiter("\\z"); //"\\z" means end of input
String input = scanner.next();
```

EDIT: If you want the `"\n"` to show as `"CR"`, just do this:

```
input.replaceAll("\\n", "CR");
```

Comment: Then the input String will include the "\n" at the end, so you can just check its length.

Comment: Count for Carriage Return does end up showing a count for "\n". With that method, I would have one issue: How do i have program label it as CR? It simply shows up as empty line with a count next to it. I tried `scanner.useDelimiter("CR:" + "\\z");` but that's probably not the solution. I cannot do `System.out.println("CR");` the line before since scanner.next() would come after that part anyways

Comment: @harshm0de It should work. Remember to store the returned value in a variable: `input = input.replaceAll("\\n", "CR");`.

Comment: @LN - for some odd reason, it works for space. So if I put in `input = input.replaceAll(" ", "S");`, space bars show up as S (it won't let me label it as 'Space' tho - only works with one single letter). It doesn't work for Carriage Return - `input = input.replaceAll("\\n, "CR");`

Comment: I believe the solution to that is `input = input.replaceAll("[\r\n]", "C");` Unfortunately, it still won't let me use more than one letter. If whatever letter I do use, it makes it so that it replaces all instances of that letter in charArray with '\n'. If I do use CR then it replaces all instances of 'C' and 'R' with '\n'. I'm guessing it has something to do with .next(); that reads one char at a time. Thanks anyways

Answer (score 0):

Read characters one by one until EOF is encountered using `read()` method.

**[JAVA DOCS](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html#read%28%29)**

read() in java reads any character(even **\n**, **\r** or **\r\n**). Thus read character one by one and check whether the character read in "Carriage return" or not.

If yes, then increase the counter.

Comment: I understand that and that is exactly what I tried, but there is one issue. If I use read(), then it tells me that the variable user_input has to be declared as an integer. I currently have it declared as a String because the input is supposed to be string. You know what I mean?

Comment: Read will return a single char value (as an int). chars and ints are similar - see this answer for an explanation: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4221225/converting-chars-to-ints-in-java/4221265#4221265

Answer (score 0):

There's a library called StringUtils that can do this very easily.  It has a method named `countMatches`.  Here's how you can use it.  But first, you should combine your input into one string:

```
package com.sandbox;

import org.apache.commons.lang.StringUtils;

public class Sandbox2 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String allInput = "this\nis\na\n\nfew\nlines\nasdf";
        System.out.println(StringUtils.countMatches(allInput, "\n"));
    }

}
```

This outputs "6".

Comment: I may be misunderstanding what you're saying, but my goal is to count how many times EACH character occurs within the entire string input. One of those characters I want to count includes carriage return. The program I have created counts the occurrences of every character within any string input BUT carriage return. I hope that clears it up a bit