# Difference between += and =+ in java?

Tags: java

I'm curious about one little thing. 
code like this:

```
    String test = "test";
    char[] test2 = {'a', 'i'};
    int i=0;
    test += test2[i] + "";
    System.out.println(test);
```

Works as we suspect, the output is "testa", but what is happening when we change operand "+=" to "=+"? Now the output is "97" and it's ascii code for an a letter, it's simple, but what happened with the whole string test? 
Thanks from advice.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4221225/converting-chars-to-ints-in-java/4221265#4221265

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The "`=+`" version:

```
test =+ test2[i] + "";
```

is parsed as

```
test = (+test2[i]) + "";
```

[The unary plus converts the char (`'a'`) to an integer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2624541/367273) (its ASCII code, `97`), which is then converted to a string (`"97"`) by the concatenation with an empty string. The end result is the string `"97"`.

Comment: Ahh I see now. Thank you very much ^-^

Answer (score 10):

`... += A` means *increase by A*.
`... =+ A` means *assign to positive A*.

If you didn't notice the difference: `a =+ b` can be rewritten as: `a = +b`. There is no `=+` operator. Where, in this case: `+'a'` gets converted to an int, because of the + operator.

Comment: Yes, it basically just the same as `= 0+A;`

Comment: It should be added that the ASCII code for the character 'a' is 97, which explains the OP's output.

Answer (score 0):

As demonstrated here: https://ideone.com/fCtLyB

```
int CONST = 75;
int method1 = 5;
int method2 = 5;
method1 += CONST; //Adds the value to method1 variable
method2 =+ CONST; //Sets method2 variable to CONST
System.out.println(method1 + ", " + method2 + ", " + CONST);
```

It's like doing `a=-5` which is really `a=0-5`, except here it's `a=+5` or `a=0+5`.

Answer (score 0):

+= is a common operator, you know what it means.
On the other hand, when you put =+ you do an assigment and converting right side to integer, sto you get integer (97).